# Equality of three probability formulas with binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I need to argue why the following three formulas are equal:

$$\binom{n+1}{k}(n-k+1) \\
\binom{n}{k}(n+1) \\
\binom{n+1}{k+1}(k+1)
$$

I've already rewritten the formulas so they equal, but I do not know how to explain why they are equal in words. The formulas describe a lottery game where k lotto numbers are drawn from n+1 numbers. Another lotto number is drawn as an additional number.

Basically, I know what the binomial coefficient does, but I do not know what the multiplication has to do with it.

Could somebody please help me here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think a little different. Suppose we have $n+1$ people, and you want to choose a chaired committee of $k+1$ members with a chairperson among the committee members. The 3 formulas correspond to 3 ways to do it:

- You can choose first $k$ members of committee and then choose a chairperson;
- You can choose first a chairperson and then choose $k$ members of committee;
- You can choose first $k+1$ members of committee and then choose a chairperson among the committee members;

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  $\ {a\choose b}=\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}\ $ and $ (a+1)! = a!(a+1)\ $. Instances of these identities are all you need to use prove that your three expressions are equal.